# Line chart with pictures?

Tags: charts, visualization, google-visualization

I want to show a line chart, each point in the line chart will refer to a user. So whomever looks at the chart understands who the user is, I'd like each point to have a picture of the user and the user's name. Does anyone know any API that will let me do that?

I was looking at googles line chart (http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html) but I cannot see anyway for me to have each data point represented as an image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems counter intuitive to have different points on the same line of a line graph represent different users.

> [(Line graphs) show in a linear form one or more variables that fluctuate over a period of time.](https://www.wadsworth.com/communication_d/templates/student_resources/0314205713_ulloth/glossary/index.html)

I believe if there is more than one variable that would mean there would be more than one line, so it is hard to make suggestions without more information about your specific application. With the currently available data I would recommend [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/javascript-based-soundcloud-player-using-amcharts/)'s [Column chart with images on top](https://web.archive.org/web/20121010160532/http://www.amcharts.com/javascript/column-chart-with-images-on-top/):

[image: Picture.png]

Answer (score 0):

Using Java and JavaFX, you can build a StackPane where you can put two charts (one above other), where the back is a LineChart and the front is a ScatterChart. In this case, these charts will share the same X axis and Y axis, and on ScatterChart you can personalize the points with a picture.
Look:
[How to personalize a chart style using Javafx](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm#CIHGIAGE) and 
[How to produce an application with more than one chart in a StackPane](https://gist.github.com/MaciejDobrowolski/9c99af00668986a0a303)

I hope this helps you.